# linux: PHP doesn't build ANY libraries

Tags: php, centos

OS: Centos

I've downloaded php 5.3.6 source, configured it with these options:

```
./configure --disable-cgi --enable-fpm --with-mcrypt --with-zlib --enable-mbstring --with-curl --disable-debug --disable-rpath --enable-inline-optimization --with-bz2 --with-zlib --enable-sockets --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-pcntl --enable-mbregex --with-mhash --enable-zip --with-pcre-regex --enable-soap --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql --with-pdo-sqlite --enable-sockets
```

then did

> make

and

> make install

Everything installed ok, besides ANY libraries, like php_pdo_sqlite.so, php_mysqli.so, NOTHING.
I've searched for them on entire system but they're nowhere to be found.

Am I doing something wrong? It's driving me insane.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Nevermind,

> yum install

saved the day as usual =/
Had to install eveything this way

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! If this solved your question, add an answer below and please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing 'yum install' to install the entire package with everything in the correct places.